# Ungrounded house (Sweden)

Tags: electrical, grounding

I got a very old timber house in the forest in Sweden: there is a fuse box, but everything is ungrounded. Which are my options to add some safety, at least in the kitchen?

On the web I found references to GFCI outlets, but I don't see anything like this in local shops here in Sweden...

Comment: Think Europe uses what is called RCM(?) circuit breakers.  Do not know if they have any replacement outlets you could use.  Would talk to a local electrician/electrical shop to find the right local information.  GFCI is mainly for North American systems.

Comment: RCD - Residual Current Device - is the common global term.

Comment: Interesting read on terminology: https://chintglobal.com/blog/difference-between-mcb-mccb-rcb-rcd-rccb-rcbo/

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, we use an Earth Leakage Circuit Breaker to control the supply to the whole house.

Then each circuit is protected by MCB (Miniature Circuit Breaker) or RCD (Residual Current Device). The RCD compares the current TO the device with the current FROM the device and turns off if they are different by a sufficient amount.

The ELCB has a 10mm^2 earth cable to a copper grounding rod outside. The performance of that would need checking.

You should discuss this with the local qualified electricians ie ones who are certified to see what is the best route for you.