# How to Ground Electrical on an Old House

Tags: grounding

I obtained a house in South Dakota, built in 1905. The electrical is problematic with more brownouts than my neighbors get.

I replaced the knob and tube wiring with 12/3 solid Romex and brought the grounds to the main panel. I noticed in the process that a prior owner used 12/2 Romex and grounded individual outlets to a solid seamless copper water pipe coming out of the ground. The location of that pipe is away from the main panel. It would be difficult to get a ground wire to the panel from those outlets.

Further, the main panel is connected to what looks like a zinc pipe encased into a concrete foundation. This doesn't seem right. I have tried to get electricians to fix things, but usually they decline the work. The existing ground rod has greater than 25 Ohms resistance. One electrician said he would only work on it if he could rewire the whole house for $15k or more, if additional work was needed. That was before inflation hit.

I was thinking of pounding an 8 foot copper rod into the ground two feet from the house and 8 feet from the currently encased zinc rod. I would bond the two with #6 wire. My concern is whether this might cause a ground loop with the outlets attached to the water pipe 20 feet away. I have heavy clay soil.
Should I disconnect the outlets grounded to the water pipe and install GFCI outlets in those locations instead? Are there any suggestions?

Edit: I apologize, I did use 12/2 Romex. Also, the grounds to the water pipe are all 14 gauge and separate from the Romex going to the panel.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/260005/97780

Comment: Just how hard would it be to get a single #6 bare copper wire from the water pipe entrance to the main panel?

Comment: Not quite sure how that applies, @SolarMike, You may want to add an explanation for those of us who are a bit more dense.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNZC782SzAQ&t=1121s

Comment: 12/3 has 3 insulated wires (black, white, red) + 1 uninsulated ground wire, while 12/2 has 2 insulated wires (black & white) + 1 uninsulated ground wire. Are you sure you used 12/3? Why?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, For some of the outlets, it would be a challenge drilling holes in the beams.  These are 6-8 inches apart.  The furthest outlets are behind fieldstone (large rocks/boulders).  They used a 14 gauge ground.

Comment: @Eric -- if you can run a 6AWG wire from the panel to a point where it can parallel the water pipe and then parallel the pipe run from there to where it enters the ground, we can kill two birds with one stone

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Thank you for the clarification.  That is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

A solid zinc plated (that's called "galvanized") rod that goes into the reinforcing-rod mesh of your concrete, is called an "Ufer Ground".  It is the best grounding electrode money can buy.  It's the gold standard in the UK for electric car charging pads, and they're nuts about grounding over there.

My problem with your question is that your root concern (flickering lights) has absolutely nothing to do with the line of examination (Grounding Electrode System) that you're dragging us on.  **Grounding is a safety shield. It is not involved in any way with delivering power to your appliances and lights**. If you throw a clamp meter around any wire in the grounding system it should read 0.0 amps.  If it reads something else, then something is broken, and it's *not* the grounding system.

(Well, current on the grounding system does not certify the grounding system as flawless: it might have problems separate from your real problem, but chasing ground problems is definitely a distraction and not a solution. I mean *it never hurts* to give the GES a once-over to make sure it's tip top, but I would not expect to solve the original problem by doing so.)

### More likely, a hot or neutral from the utility

Loads are connected among the two hot wires and neutral. Low voltage there indicates a problem with those wires.  Ground is not a player.

The two most common failures we get are a "lost neutral" and a "lost hot".

A lost neutral means you have 240V across your two hot wires, but neutral is no longer pinned in the middle. It now floats, causing a see-saw of voltages -  130V and 110V...... or 90V and 150V... depending on what the loads are at that instant.   This is usually a problem with the utility.  They can't remotely detect that because a common 4-jaw meter does not have access to neutral.

Most modern appliances are pretty tolerant of varying voltage, so you can go a long time without realizing you have this problem.

A lost hot is indicated by every other row of 120V breakers in your panel losing power, **except when a 240V load tries to kick in**, and then, power weakly restores on that dead side.  Water heaters kick on and off randomly, so they will cause mystery behavior.  An unusually slow-to-recover water heater is a red flag for this problem. So is "if I turn my oven on, all my circuits come back!"

Most of the time, both failures are from the utility's service drop wires, and they fix that for free.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  The power company came out and confirmed there was a loose wire coming to the house.  They tightened that down.  They would not give more specifics, but the brownouts stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Current code requires (and has for a long time) all metal pipes (gas, both hot and cold water pipes) to be connected to the ground bus bar in the main panel and 2 ground rods at least 8' apart to also be connected to the ground bus bar. Don't worry about a "ground loop": that doesn't exist. The purpose of connecting all grounding together is to **eliminate** the possibility of an appliance or device become externally energized and create a shock hazard.  GFCIs are required in potentially wet locations such as kitchens, bathrooms, garages and outdoor outlets.

Bottom line:  Don't disconnect any ground from outlets, it's there for a reason.  If you really worried about this, there's nothing stopping you from installing additional GFCI protected outlets or even GFCI breakers in your main panel.

Lastly one question:  Why 12/3? 12/2 is fine.  What did you do with the 3rd conductor?

Comment: Thank you George for the information.  As noted above, I fat fingered it and did use 12/2.  I did not know about grounding the metal pipes to the ground bus bar.  I haven't seen that out here.  Can I assume this also include the metal pipe coming from the heating oil tank?